# How do I use a package variable inside a Script task?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Currently, I have a file path value hard coded inside the Script task of an SSIS package.

I have a string variable sPath. How should I use this variable sPath inside Script Task?

```
string strPath = "C:\\File.xls";
if( File.Exists(strPath))
{
    File.Delete(strPath);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is one possible way of using variables inside `Script Task`. Assuming that you have a variable named **FilePath** declared on your package as shown in screenshot #**1** then you can use the following code to use the variable inside the `Script Task`. this is one of the possible ways to use the variable. Here the variable is used only to read the value using the method `LockForRead`. You can also write values to the variable if the variable is declared with `LockForWrite` method.

By the way, the functionality described in the `Scrip Task` code can also be carried out using the `File System Task` available in SSIS `Control Flow` task list.

Hope that helps.

**Using package variables inside Script Task:**

**C#** code that can be used only in **`SSIS 2008 and above`**.
.

```
public void Main()
{
    Variables varCollection = null;
    string FilePath = string.Empty;

    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::FilePath");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

    FilePath = varCollection["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();

    if (File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        File.Delete(FilePath);
    }

    varCollection.Unlock();

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

Comment: Thats the perfect answer !! Thank you

Comment: Don't know why this hasn't been accepted.
Very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Which namespaces should we including in our `using` statements for the compiler to resolve the `Variables` declaration?

I had to replace `Variables` with `IDTSVariables100` and also replace the `ref` modifier with `out` when calling the `GetVariables` method.